# Flutter on VS Code You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle

Tags: flutter

I cloned a flutter project and tried running it on my windows desktop vs code. When I try to run `flutter run`, I get the following error:

```
[!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle.                                   │
│                                                                                                                 │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on https://developer.android.com/studio/install. │
│                                                                                                                 │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.
```

I dont understand why I need to update Android Studio to the latest version when I am using VS Code for flutter. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so weird. I installed jdk-11 from oracle but it didnt work. But when I updated Android Studio and then running the flutter program in VS Code, it run without any problem. I still dont understand why it worked but the solution was to just update android studio.

Comment: Because on updating android studio the latest java version (19) was installed.

Comment: @SuPythony I checked the version of my Java, it's still Java 8 though.